# swift 1.2 - grouping tuples by first element

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, tuples

I have an array of various `tuple`. I want to create a `for` loop that adds the second part of the `tuple`, if the first part is the same.

For example I am looking for the result:

> (2014,11) (2015,13)

The code which I have produced is below:

```
var tuple = (Int, Double)
var array = [tuple]
array.append((2014,3),(2014,2),(2014,6),(2015,8),(2015,5)]
var temp = 0

for i in array {
    if tuple.0 = tuple.0 {
    temp += temp
    }
}
```

This does not group by year as I was expecting. Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: That code does not even compile ...

Comment: Is this sort of a college assignment?  It could help to get better answers if the code does at least something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want (in Swift 2):

```
var dict: Dictionary<Int, Int> = [:]
for t in array {
    dict[t.0] = (dict[t.0] ?? 0) + t.1
}
```

Well, sort of... The result would be `[2014 : 11, 2015 : 13]`

Comment: Thanks Marcos! This is exactly what I was looking for. 

If i wanted to sort this array by the highest key in the dictionary how would this be achieved? I tried 'sorted(dict) {$0.1 < $1.1 }' however it didn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: @JessMurray: The result is a dictionary, not an array. Dictionary have no order and there-for cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

As [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110823/106435) I'd say that a dictionary might be the better data structure to use, but if you insist on saving in an tuple array, you can use some higher order function madness, Swift 2 (why would you use 1.2?):

```
let array = [(2014,3),(2014,2),(2014,6),(2015,8),(2015,5)]
let keys = Set(array.map{return $0.0})
let result = keys.map{(k:Int) -> (Int,Int) in (k, array.filter{ $0.0 == k }.map{ $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine:+))}

print(result)
```

---

Result

```
[(2014, 11), (2015, 13)]
```

---

note, that a Set does not guarantee the order of its elements. in fact it has no order. 
To ensure the order you can use `sort{$0.0 < $1.0}`

```
let result = keys.map{(k:Int) -> (Int,Int) in (k, array.filter{ $0.0 == k }.map{ $0.1 }.reduce(0, combine:+))}.sort{$0.0 < $1.0}
```

---

One advantage over the dictionary solution is the ability to sort.

```
let result = ....sort{$0.0 < $1.0}
```

-> `[(2014, 11), (2015, 13)]`

```
let result = ....sort{$0.0 > $1.0}
```

-> `[(2015, 13), (2014, 11)]`

```
 let result = ....sort{$0.1 > $1.1}
```

-> `[(2015, 13), (2014, 11)]`

```
let result = ....sort{$0.1 < $1.1}
```

-> `[(2014, 11), (2015, 13)]`